# test command object validation

Tags: unit-testing, validation, grails, groovy

I have the following command object:

```
class CategoryCommand {

    String name
    String seoName

    static constraints = {
        name(blank: false)
        seoName(blank: false)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to test the constraint validation using this test case:

```
class ValidationTests extends ControllerUnitTestCase {


    protected void setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        mockCommandObject(CategoryCommand)
    }

    void testValidation() {
        def command = new CategoryCommand()
        assertFalse command.validate()
    }
}
```

But the assertion fails because the command object passes validation, even though the constraints are violated.

My guess is that this is not working either because `mockCommandObject` adds a `validate()` method, but the implementation of this method always returns `true`

Is there another way I can test validation of a command class. I need both the `validate()` and `errors` property to work as they do when running the app in order to test it properly. I've tried running this as both an integration and unit test, but the result is the same.

Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer, since I forgot that I was adding hasErrors to metaClass of my command object to able to use it in unit test.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `mockCommandObject` in tests:

```
mockCommandObject(CategoryCommand)
```

It allows you to use `validate()` method and access the `errors` property easily. I made bunch of unit tests for command objects and it works very well in my case.

**EDIT**

I noticed some strange behaviour, basically don't know why. I have a command object:

```
class ChangePasswordCommand {
  String oldPassword
  String newPassword
  String newPassword2

  static constraints = {
    oldPassword(blank: false)
    newPassword(blank: false, matches: ConfigurationHolder.config.application.password.regex)
    newPassword2(blank: false, validator: { val, obj ->
      if (val != obj.newPassword) {
        return 'registration.password.mismatch.error'
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I also have the test (and `mockCommandObject(ChangePasswordCommand)` in `setUp()` method ):

```
    void testChangePasswordCommand_errors() {
            def cmd = new ChangePasswordCommand(oldPassword: '', newPassword: 'SomePass', newPassword2: 'SomeOtherPass')
            //def cmd = new ChangePasswordCommand()

            assertFalse cmd.validate()
            assertTrue cmd.hasErrors()
            assertEquals 3, cmd.errors.getErrorCount()
            assertEquals 'blank', cmd.errors.getFieldError('oldPassword').getCode()
            assertEquals 'matches.invalid', cmd.errors.getFieldError('newPassword').getCode()
            assertEquals 'registration.password.mismatch.error', cmd.errors.getFieldError('newPassword2').getCode()
}
```

When I run the test, it passes. But when I comment the first line, and uncomment the second, so that empty command object is put into testing, test fails on `cmd.validate()` assertion. Also, when I comment the `cmd.validate()` assertion, it also fails on asserting `cmd.hasErrors()`. Then I removed oldPassword property setting in the first line

`def cmd = new ChangePasswordCommand(newPassword: 'SomePass', newPassword2: 'SomeOtherPass')`

and test failed as well. So it looks like it it brakes because of `null` property value. I can't explain this.

**EDIT 2**

I'm blind or something. `mockCommandObject` adds `validate()` method, but it doesn't add `hasErrors()` method. In my test, in `setUp()` I have also:

```
ChangePasswordCommand.metaClass.hasErrors() { !delegate.validate() }
```

Comment: Both `mockForConstraintsTests` and `mockCommandObject` call the same `grails.test.MockUtils.addValidateMethod`.

Comment: I changed the test to call `mockCommandObject` but the result is the same. I've updated the question

Comment: I edited my answer because I ran some tests on my project. I noticed some strange behaviour, but can't explain why.

Comment: I don't why I didn't find it earlier, but I add hasErrors method to metaClass of my command object to be able to use it in unit test. Edited answer appropriately.